# How do independent components communicate in ember?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-components

How do I let independent component let know of changes or events in a component?

eg:

```
 <#user-social profile>
  {{partial 'user-handle'}}

  <div class='subtext'> 
    {{#reply-component}} {{/reply-component}}
  </div>

  <div class='replybox hide'>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type='button' value='Reply to user' />
  </div>
 </user-social profile>
```

Problem: I want `replybox` to toggle its visibility when a link inside reply component is clicked.

Comment: Inside reply-component, you can access user-social using the 'parentView' property. So when the link is is click set a value in the parent component like this.set('parentView.isToggle', false); and you can make reply box bind to that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components are isolated by design. It’s your responsibility to specify their dependencies. You can introduce communication channels between a parent and child component either by passing bound attributes to the child or specifying actions for the child to trigger on the parent.

Actions are probably a better fit, as using two-way bindings as a form of communication is increasingly considered an anti-pattern. An example:

```
{{#reply-component toggleReplybox="toggleReplybox"}}
```

Then, in your child component:

```
actions: {
  whateverTriggersTheToggle: function() {
    this.sendAction('toggleReplybox');
  }
}
```

You’d have to add the `whateverTriggersTheToggle` action to something inside the child component.

In the parent component:
    displayReplybox: false,

```
actions: {
  toggleReplybox: function() {
    this.set('displayReplybox', !this.get('displayReplybox'));
  }
}
```

This would necessitate adding an `{{#if displayReplybox}}` wrapper around your `replybox` element.

Comment: "using two-way bindings as a form of communication is increasingly considered an anti-pattern" - I thought the opposite... do you have any post/article/tweet/anything from ember core team about this?

Comment: It’s mentioned in [The Road to Ember 2.0 RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) under the heading “One-Way Bindings by Default” (wish I could link to that directly). Tom Dale and Yehuda Katz also go into some detail about it on their [appearance on The Changelog](http://thechangelog.com/131/).

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's great. Even though I read that post before, I somehow missed it.

Comment: Maybe it’s because it’s novel-length! haha. These concepts will take a while to trickle into the release version, so we have time to adapt.

Comment: one more question... what about the communication between the controller and the component? do you think bound properties are the better approach in this case? I was actually referring to that problem, not the components talking to each other.

Comment: It seems the general trend that actions are preferred over bindings as a form of communication. Controllers are supposedly also going away in Ember 2.0, but I don’t think they’re that different conceptually from components that they would be a special case.

Comment: @BuckDoyle The actions are not bubbled back to the parent component, but the controller and then the route hierarchy. They skip the parent component.
I don't see how `this.sendAction('toggleReplybox')` will cause `toggleReplybox` action in parent component getting called.

Comment: @mikeazo My mistake!! yes it does!!